# Enable button only if text field contains text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a text field and a button that's disabled by default. If the user types something in the text field and then leaves the field, the button should become enabled.

Why doesn't my code work as expected? Here is a [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/abcid/FEpsn/1/).

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="txtInput"></input>
<button class="buttEnable" disabled="disabled">Submit</button>
```

JS

```
$('#txtInput').keyup(
    function()
    {
        if( (this).val() == '');
        {
            $('.buttEnable').prop('disabled', 'true');
        }
        else
        {
            $('.buttEnable').prop('disable' , 'false');
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Your code has a lot of issues. For example, consider the semicolon after the if, the use of "disable" in the else condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use `blur` instead of `keyup` cause you said "as soon as leave the field"

**js**

```
$('#txtInput').on("blur", function(){
    if($(this).val().length > 0 ){
        $(this).next(".buttEnable").attr("disabled",false);
    }
    else{
        $(this).next(".buttEnable").attr("disabled","disabled");
    }

});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FEpsn/3/)

Comment: Thank you very much!  Yes, `blur` is fit in this case. It works .

Comment: Just a note: The jQuery team [recommends](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/12/jquery-1-6-1-released/) using `prop` instead of `attr` when setting `disabled`, although both will work.

Comment: After the button is enable, I want to change its background color.  In else statement, I add `$('button').addClass('buttBlue');` ( [link](http://jsfiddle.net/abcid/FEpsn/5/) sample's here).  Somehow the button's background color doesn't turn blue?  Please help!

Comment: You have some errors. Check this updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/FEpsn/8/ . Also `addClass` should be in first if statement. Also you have to use `removeClass` when the button disabled again. :)

Answer (score 3):

The original code has several errors:

- There's a missing `$` in `(this).val()`.
- There's an extra semicolon after the `if` condition.
- `true` and `false` should not be quoted.
- `disable` is misspelled in the `else` branch.

In addition, if you want to enable/disable the button only when the user leaves the field, instead of immediately after the user types a character, then you should use `change` instead of `keyup`.

Here's a rewritten version which fixes the errors and also eliminates some duplicate code:

```
$('#txtInput').change(
    function()
    {
        var isEmpty = !$(this).val();
        $('.buttEnable').prop('disabled', isEmpty);
    });
```

**UPDATE:** If you also want to add a CSS class when the button is enabled, you can call `toggleClass`:

```
        $('.buttEnable').prop('disabled', isEmpty)
            .toggleClass('buttBlue', !isEmpty);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out these errors!  After these errors were correct, it works.  Also, please explain what does `!$` mean in this case?  Thanks

Comment: I admit `!$` might look confusing. `!` is the Boolean NOT operator, and due to operator precedence, it's actually being applied to the entire expression `$(this).val()`. In other words, if you add redundant parentheses, it's equivalent to `!($(this).val())`. For a string, `!s` is equivalent to `s != ''`. So `!$(this).val()` is shorthand for `$(this).val() != ''`.